# Is it possible to replace the default dialer in Windows Phone 7.5\8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm researching about the technological options for an idea I'm turning into a product.

From some scattered information on the web, I came to understand that replacing the default dialer is not possible. However, searching the WP store brings several [dialers](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/search?q=dialer). Since I do not own\have a Windows Phone, I am not sure whether these dialers are just apps added to the metro.... or something tht actually becomes the default dialer.

**My Question:** I'd like to intercept the call when it is placed by the phone owner, do some manipulations and then either run my own app or pass it to the default dialer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible, there aren't any events that you can hook into when the device receives a phone call.

The apps you refer to are just that, apps, and although they look like a replacement to the dialer, they are infact just screens constructed to look this way.

They hook into the PhoneCallTask, a link to how to use this is as follows :-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394025%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Additional dialers are merely applications, it's not possible to replace/change the default dialer in Windows Phone 7.~